# Android: Getting an error "Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views"

Tags: android, multithreading, handler, progressdialog, runnable

I've been working on this problem all day and I'm ready to pull my hair out.  I found some answers here and on the web that say that this is caused by trying to do something with a View within the thread (instead of in the UI thread).  But I've tried all of the ideas (handler/new thread) that I've seen and still can't get it to work.  I programmed in C for many years as a hobby and now I'm a newbie at Java/Android.  I'm programming with Eclipse and the Android 2.1 platform.  I want my application to work with as many of the Android phones as possible and I think all of the features that I'm using are compatible with API 1. I also saw that there is something called AsyncTask, but will that cause a problem with people who have old phones?

So here is what my app does.  When I click on a button, the app goes online to a website and downloads an xml/rss feed.  Then it parses it and puts the data into a listview using a custom adapter that I created.  The downloading and parsing can take anywhere from 1 second to 15 seconds, so I wanted to add a progress dialog.  After adding that, that is where I started getting the error message in the title of this post. The app does the downloading successfully (my example xml file on the web has 8 records in it so it's very small) but then I see the error before the listview is displayed.  So I guess I need to know exactly which part of the view is causing the error, and then how to fix it.

Here is the code (I have removed all of my testing code from the last few hours so it is clean and will be less confusing to all of you... and me):

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ClubMessageList extends ListActivity implements Serializable
{
private static final String TAG = "DGMS News";
private ArrayList<CMessage> m_messages = null;
private MessageAdapter m_adapter;
private ProgressDialog m_ProgressDialog = null; 
private Runnable downloadMessages;
// Need handler for callbacks to the UI thread
final Handler mHandler = new Handler();

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle)
{
    Log.i(TAG, "Starting the ClubMessageList activity");
    super.onCreate(icicle);

    setContentView(R.layout.list);
    setTitle("DGMS News - Clubs");

    try
    {
        // check to see if we already have downloaded messages available in the bundle
        m_messages = (ArrayList<CMessage>) ((icicle == null) ? null : icicle.getSerializable("savedMessages"));

        // if there are no messages in the bundle, download them from the web and then display them
        if (m_messages == null)
        {
            m_messages = new ArrayList<CMessage>();
            this.m_adapter = new MessageAdapter(this, R.layout.row_club, (ArrayList<CMessage>) m_messages);
            setListAdapter(this.m_adapter);

            downloadMessages = new Runnable(){
                public void run() {
                    getMessages();
                }
            };
            Thread thread =  new Thread(null, downloadMessages, "DownloadMessages");
            thread.start();
            m_ProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(ClubMessageList.this,    
                  "Please wait...", "Retrieving 2010 Show data ...", true);
        }
        else // messages were already downloaded, so display them in the listview (don't download them again)
        {
            Log.i("DGMS News", "Starting activity again. Data exists so don't retrieve it again.");
            m_adapter = new MessageAdapter(this, R.layout.row_club, (ArrayList<CMessage>) m_messages);
            this.setListAdapter(m_adapter);
        }
    }
    catch (Throwable t)
    {
        Log.e("DGMS News",t.getMessage(),t);
    }
}

private Runnable returnRes = new Runnable()
{
    public void run()
    {
        if(m_messages != null && m_messages.size() > 0)
        {
            m_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            for(int i=0;i<m_messages.size();i++)
                m_adapter.add(m_messages.get(i));
        }
        m_ProgressDialog.dismiss();
        m_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
};

private void getMessages()
{
    try
    {
        m_messages = new ArrayList<CMessage>();
        ClubFeedParser parser = ClubFeedParserFactory.getParser();
        m_messages = parser.parse();
        for(int i = 0; i < m_messages.size(); i++)
            m_adapter.add(m_messages.get(i));
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    { 
        Log.e("DGMS News", e.getMessage());
    }
    runOnUiThread(returnRes);
}

protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
{
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putSerializable("savedMessages", (Serializable) m_messages);
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
{
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    Intent intent = new Intent(ClubMessageList.this, ClubDetails.class);
    // Add all info about the selected club to the intent
    intent.putExtra("title", m_messages.get(position).getTitle());
    intent.putExtra("location", m_messages.get(position).getLocation());
    intent.putExtra("website", m_messages.get(position).getLink());
    intent.putExtra("email", m_messages.get(position).getEmail());
    intent.putExtra("city", m_messages.get(position).getCity());
    intent.putExtra("contact", m_messages.get(position).getContact());
    intent.putExtra("phone", m_messages.get(position).getPhone());
    intent.putExtra("description", m_messages.get(position).getDescription());

    startActivity(intent);
}

private class MessageAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CMessage> implements Serializable
{
    private ArrayList<CMessage> items;

    public MessageAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<CMessage> items)
    {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
        this.items = items;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.row_club, null);

            CMessage m = items.get(position);
            if (m != null)
            {
                TextView ltt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.ltoptext);
                TextView rtt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.rtoptext);
                TextView lbt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.lbottext);

                if (ltt != null)
                    ltt.setText(m.getTitle());

                if (rtt != null)
                    rtt.setText(m.getLocation());

                if (lbt != null)
                    lbt.setText(m.getCity() + ", CO");

                //if (rbt != null)
                    ; // not used in this list row
            }
        }
        return v;
    }
}
}
```

As I said, all of that code worked fine until I added the progress dialog stuff that I found on another website a few days ago.

I appreciate any and all help, although I have already gone to the Android Developers website to look at threading, handlers, etc and it just got me more and more confused. Actual code changes would be awesome.  :-)  My head is hurting after looking at so many websites today.

Thanks!

Bob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
              runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                  m_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                  m_adapter.add(m_messages.get(i));

                 m_ProgressDialog.dismiss();
                 m_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


            }
        });
```

All your Ui code must go in runOnUiThread. The error u r getting is you are trying to update UI from other thread than the activity UI thread.

this thread in your code is causing the problem.

```
               private Runnable returnRes = new Runnable()
             {
                public void run()
                {
              if(m_messages != null && m_messages.size() > 0)
             {
                m_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                for(int i=0;i<m_messages.size();i++)
                m_adapter.add(m_messages.get(i));
              }
           m_ProgressDialog.dismiss();
           m_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
         }
          };
```

Comment: @user593424: Thanks! That fixed it. And I was actually loading the list twice in my code, so I fixed that too. Very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Use AsyncTask. Almost no phones are using Android 1.0/1.1 at this point (the only phone that ever even shipped with Android < 1.5 was the HTC G1, and most were upgraded OTA a looong time ago) . If you really need to support those devices, you can use the identical `UserTask`. See [this article](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html) for more info. And see about a dozen SO questions about making sure you update the UI from the main thread.

Comment: Hi Yoni!  Thank you for your answer.  I will try your suggestion as soon as I can.  If I can get it to work, I will replace the existing code with it.  :-)